# Eclipse 2019-03 C/C++ lldb debugger setup on macOS Catalina

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging, lldb

I'm trying to set up lldb debugger on Eclipse and I follow this link https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F

Follow by the paragraph "How do I install the LLDB debugger integration?", the content is out-of-date and I try to google but still can't find the answer. My problems are:

1. In my Eclipse Help > Install new Software, I can find any C/C++ LLDB Debugger Integration option to install.
2. I'm using Xcode version 12 and it no longer support lldb-mi.

Can anyone help me on this thank you.

Answer (score 1):

lldb-mi is no longer part of the basic lldb distribution, but you can get the sources (and instructions on building it) here:

https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi